# Fetching my property values in NSMutable array in iOS

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray

I have following code and unable to fetch the items saved:

```
-(IBAction)saveButtonClicked:(UIButton *)sender  
{  

   [myViewModel.itemsList addObject:myViewModel.items];
   NSLog(@"Length of array .. %d", myViewModel.itemsList.count);

}
```

Above, I save my array of objects and below try to fetch the same array of objects. 
But, array of object (itemsList's items object has property name and desc. When I try to fetch myArray.name it says, no such property.

```
-(IBAction)submitButtonClicked:(UIButton *)sender
{
      UIAlertView *alert= [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Successful!"] message:@"Submitted successfuly!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
     [alert show];


    for(int i = 0; i< myViewModel.itemsList.count; i++){
    NSLog(@"Array..%@", [myViewModel.itemsList objectAtIndex:i]);
    NSObject *myArray = [myViewModel.itemsList objectAtIndex:i];

   }
 }
```

Comment: What is `myViewModel.items`?  Also it sounds like a job for `NSMutableDictionary` given the name/value pairs involved.

Comment: no name value pair is involved. items is a custom object including property name and desc

Comment: OK, so what is `myViewModel.items`?

Comment: myViewModel.items is a custom object including property name and desc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is almost certainly just that you've used the wrong type when fetching the object from the array:

```
NSObject *myArray = [myViewModel.itemsList objectAtIndex:i];
```

Should be:

```
MyCustomObject *item = [myViewModel.itemsList objectAtIndex:i];
```

Also use *fast enumeration* which is, err, faster and more convenient:

```
for (MyCustomObject *item in myViewModel.itemsList) {
    NSLog(@"name=%@", item.name);
}
```

Incidentally, this *would* have worked:

```
for (id item in myViewModel.itemsList) {
    NSLog(@"name=%@", [item name]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
NSObject *myArray = [myViewModel.itemsList objectAtIndex:i];
```

Do:

```
WhateverYourCustomObjectClassIsCalled *myArray = [myViewModel.itemsList objectAtIndex:i];
```